# Robot Framework - Appium Library: Security Exception while starting the application

Tags: android, appium, robotframework

I want to test an android application and I have to use Robot Framework and Appium Library. 
Since I am new to Robot Framework, I have created a demo app and test, which simply launches the application. However, I get the below error on appium server:

```
    [MJSONWP] Encountered internal error running command: Error: Cannot start the 'g
r.cosmote.testcosmoteidsdk' application. Original error: Error executing adbExec
. Original error: 'Command 'C\:\\Users\\usl014\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk\\pl
atform-tools\\adb.exe -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell am start -W -n gr.cosmote.t
estcosmoteidsdk/gr.cosmote.testcosmoteidsdk.activities.HomeActivity -S -a androi
d.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER -f 0x10200000' exited w
ith code 4294967295'; Stderr: 'Security exception: Permission Denial: starting I
ntent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] fl
g=0x10200000 cmp=gr.cosmote.testcosmoteidsdk/.activities.HomeActivity } from nul
l (pid=9049, uid=2000) not exported from uid 10081
[MJSONWP]
[MJSONWP] java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=
android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000
 cmp=gr.cosmote.testcosmoteidsdk/.activities.HomeActivity } from null (pid=9049,
 uid=2000) not exported from uid 10081
[MJSONWP]       at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.checkStartAnyAc
tivityPermission(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:1632)
[MJSONWP]       at com.android.server.am.ActivityStarter.startActivity(ActivityS
tarter.java:438)
[MJSONWP]       at com.android.server.am.ActivityStarter.startActivityLocked(Act
ivityStarter.java:278)
[MJSONWP]       at com.android.server.am.ActivityStarter.startActivityMayWait(Ac
tivityStarter.java:817)
[MJSONWP]       at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivityAnd
Wait(ActivityManagerService.java:4625)
[MJSONWP]       at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerShellCommand.runStartAct
ivity(ActivityManagerShellCommand.java:412)
[MJSONWP]       at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerShellCommand.onCommand(A
ctivityManagerShellCommand.java:141)
[MJSONWP]       at android.os.ShellCommand.exec(ShellCommand.java:96)
[MJSONWP]       at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onShellCommand(A
ctivityManagerService.java:15014)
[MJSONWP]       at android.os.Binder.shellCommand(Binder.java:594)
[MJSONWP]       at android.os.Binder.onTransact(Binder.java:492)
[MJSONWP]       at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub.onTransact(IActivityManager
.java:4243)
[MJSONWP]       at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(Activ
ityManagerService.java:2919)
[MJSONWP]       at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:697)'; Code: '4294
967295'
[MJSONWP]     at ADB.callee$0$0$ (C:\Users\usl014\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modul
es\appium\node_modules\appium-adb\lib\tools\apk-utils.js:125:11)
[MJSONWP]     at tryCatch (C:\Users\usl014\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appi
um\node_modules\babel-runtime\regenerator\runtime.js:67:40)
[MJSONWP]     at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke [as _invoke] (C:\Users\usl014
\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\babel-runtime\regenerator\
runtime.js:315:22)
[MJSONWP]     at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.prototype.(anonymous function) [as t
hrow] (C:\Users\usl014\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\babe
l-runtime\regenerator\runtime.js:100:21)
[MJSONWP]     at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke (C:\Users\usl014\AppData\Roam
ing\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\babel-runtime\regenerator\runtime.js:13
6:37)
```

My test's code:

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation    Suite description
Library  AppiumLibrary

*** Variables ***
${REMOTE_URL}  http://localhost:4723/wd/hub
${PLATFORM_NAME}  Android
${PLATFORM_VERSION}  8.1
${DEVICE_NAME}  Pixel 2 XL API 27
${APP}  C:/Users/usl014/PycharmProjects/robotframeworkdemo/tests/demoapp/app-debug.apk

*** Test Cases ***
Test title
    Open Application  ${REMOTE_URL}  platformName=Android  platformVersion=${PLATFORM_VERSION}  autoGrantPermissions=true  deviceName=${DEVICE_NAME}  app=${APP}  automationName=appium  appActivity=gr.cosmote.testcosmoteidsdk.activities.HomeActivity
    Capture Page Screenshot
    Close Application
```

Finally, the manifest of the application is the below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="gr.cosmote.testcosmoteidsdk">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".activities.HomeActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".activities.LoginActivity"
            android:exported="true" />
        <activity android:name=".activities.RegisterActivity"
            android:exported="true" />
        <activity android:name=".activities.GreetingActivity"
            android:exported="true" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

In the manifest, I have added android:exported="true", which is a suggestion I have found, but did not work for me. Any help will be appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you attempting to launch an emulator through your startup code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you face has nothing to do with Robotframework or Appium. It is because your activity cannot be launched.
I suggest to get rid of intent-filter and see if that helps.

Otherwise, skip Appium for now, use adb shell in terminal to make sure you fix the problem:
As soon as `am start -n yourpackagename/.activityname` will run app without an issue, you can come back to Appium

Comment: thanks for your answer. the problem was with the device which had an older apk version with different signatures. I have fixed this and the test runs normally